A proportional sequence of permutations
Each day, Grandpa gives fruit to his $n$ grandchildren, one by one. The children love fruit but hate waiting. To avoid quarrels about who gets the fruit first, Grandpa would like to change the order each day. Specifically, he wants to select a sequence of $n$ orders satisfying the following conditions:

In the first day, the order is arbitrary;
In the first two days, each child must appear at least once in the first $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ positions;
In the first three days, each child must appear at least once in the first $\lceil n/3 \rceil$ positions, and at least twice in the first $\lceil 2n/3 \rceil$ positions;
In general, for each $k$ in $1,\ldots, n$, in the first $k$ days, each child must appear at least $j$ times in the first $\lceil j n/k \rceil$ positions, for all $j$ in $1,\ldots,k-1$;

Note that the condition for $k=n$ is that, overall, each child must appear at least $j$ times in the first $j$ positions; this means that each child must appear exactly once in each position.
A sequence satisfying these conditions is called proportional. A proportional sequence for $n=1$ and $n=2$ exists trivially, and I could also find a proportional sequence for some larger values of $n$:

$n=3$: 123, 231, 312.
$n=4$: 1234, 4321, 3412, 2143.
$n=5$: 12345, 34512, 51234, 45123, 23451.
$n=6$: 123456, 456123, 362514, 514362, 235641, 641235.

Does there exist a proportional sequence for any $n$?

If $n=2^k$ for a natural number $k$, I don't think you can get much more efficient than a binary odometer type of mapping.  Also, it's called the von Neumann-Kakutani adding machine in ergodic theory.  It's a cycle on the set $\{1,2,\ldots, 2^k\}$ or usually written $\{0,1,\ldots,2^k-1\}$.  Here's an example for $n=8$:
$$1\to 5\to 3\to 7\to 2\to 6\to 4\to 8 \to 1.$$
The way this works, wherever you start, say position=$7$, then you just cycle through the sequence: $7\to 2\to 6\to 4\to 8\to 1\to 5\to 3$.  It looks like this mapping gives you what you want, but I don't have a proof yet.  What I'm doing is applying the binary odometer:
$$000 \to 100 \to 010\to 110\to 001\to 101\to 011\to 111$$ which gives:
$$0\to 4\to 2\to 6\to 1\to 5\to 3\to 7.$$ It's more convenient to number the children starting at $0$ and then add one to get your numbering.
Here's the ordering for $n=16$.
$$0000 \to 1000 \to 0100\to 1100\to 0010\to 1010\to 0110\to 1110\to 
0001 \to 1001 \to 0101\to 1101\to 0011\to 1011\to 0111\to 1111$$ which translates to:
$$1,9,5,13,3,11,7,15,2,10,6,14,4,12,8,16.$$
There is an interval exchange transformation which could be used to get the mapping for any positive integer $n$, but then a proof is still needed!  I hope this helps.  There was no way to type this into the comments.  Thank you for your question!
I have a general procedure for the ordering, including integers which are not powers of $2$.  It's easier to explain with an example.  Suppose $n=11$.  Let $k$ be the largest integer such that $2^k\leq n$.  So, $2^k=8$.  Compute $\lceil \frac{11*j}{8} \rceil$ for $0\leq j<8$.  We get:
$$0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10.$$ Use the binary odometer method on this sequence to get the ordering: $0, 6, 3, 9, 2, 7, 5, 10$.  Then cycle back to fill in the rest: $0,6,3,9,2,7,5,10,1, 4, 8$.  Add one to each number to start the sequence at $1$:
$$1,7,4,10,3,8,6,11,2,5,9.$$  So, if a child was 10 in the first round, then that child would be $3^{\mbox{rd}}$ in the second, $8^{\mbox{th}}$ in the third round and so on, eventually ending at $4^{\mbox{th}}$ in the $11^{\mbox{th}}$ round.

So for $n=8$, the sequence in the first day is 12345678, in the second day 56781234, in the third day 34567812, etc.?

What do you mean by "cycle back to fill in the rest" - how exactly to cycle back?

It's a good question for how to cycle back.  It looks like the sequence is not proportional for $n=11$.  If $k=3$ is a 3 day stretch, then one of the children has the order: 8,6,11 which does not give them at least once in the first 4 positions: $\lceil \frac{11}{3} \rceil = 4$.  I suspect it's not possible for every $n$.  This is a very interesting question!

I'm not sure exactly what notation you're using. For $n=8$, I think you want $56783421$ on the second day and $34217865$ on the third day. Also, it can be written, child 1's order each day: $15372648$, child 2's order each day: $53726481$, child 3's order: $37264815$ and so on. It might improve the proportionality slightly to switch a couple of them, so that it goes: $16382547$.  I'm not sure this gives you what you want.  It seemed like a proportional sequence, but I was numbering from 0,..., 7.
